# Can a non-Muslim have sex with her Muslim spouse after the Ramadan fast has broken?

Tags: sharia, sawm, non-muslim

We have been married for six months now. Ramadan starts tomorrow and my husband just told me last week, that we cannot have sex due to the fact that I'm non-Muslim, I'm Anglican.

So I was just wanting to know if this is true? Can we not have sex once the fast has been broken?

Answer (score 5):

You can not have sex during the fast but after it is over, till it starts the next day, you can have sex. God allowed in [Quran](http://quran.com/2/187). There is no distinction between a muslim or non-muslim wife.

> It has been made permissible for you the night preceding fasting to go to your wives [for sexual relations].

Comment: Thanks so much. Now I'm thinking that he just does not want to have sex cause I'm not muslim.

Comment: hi [Original Poster](http://islam.stackexchange.com/users/2772/user2772), do not think like that, Prophet Muhammad often pray in Ramadhan cause he want to pray to Allah more intensive. I think your husband do it to cause it is sunnah (good to do). Just ask lovely to your husband at night if you need to have sex with him.

Comment: I have only asked because I did not no the answer. But i will respect my husbands wishes though, I'm not gunna force him to have sex just because I want to. He has already told me that he wont because I'm not muslim so I'm not even going to bother.

Comment: Off-topic comment: Please approve edits carefully (http://islam.stackexchange.com/review/suggested-edits/14727). The system has trusted you to do that.